# Is the package name / domain of my Android app important?

Tags: android, google-play

I created an Android app using a package name of (for example) com.myawesomeapp.android.

I had purchased myawesomeapp.com, but I'm no longer interested in keeping the domain itself, but want to keep the app.

Is there any danger in letting the domain expire? If someone else later registers the domain, is there any way they could request control of the app from Google?

Thanks!

Comment: No, they can't. You're safe.

Comment: i don't think there is any danger. App package name and domain name are not related.

Comment: As mentioned above, no, no one can wrest control of your apps away from you if they take over that domain name. The main reason it is suggested to use a domain that you own is to help ensure the uniqueness of your package names. Your apps are not "tied" to that domain in any other way, and ownership of that domain does not entitle anyone else any control whatsoever over your published apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owning a domain name has nothing to do with it.  You can choose any package name you want, for your app.  The combination of the app package name and your cert, *are* your app.  Any bag of bits with that name and that cert *are* your app.

Same cert, different package name?  Another app you created.

Same package, different cert?  First install wins.  If some user installs my app, with my cert and a given package name, and then tries tries to install *your* app, same package name, different cert, Android will refuse the second installation.

It turns out that your app's package name becomes the name, essentially, of the user directory, on the device, which is the root for all of your application's persistent storage

Btw, this has nothing at all to do with the java package you use for your application.  Aapt, the resource compiler will uses the application package name as the java package for the java code it generates.  If you happen to use the same package for your java code, then all the normal java rules apply: you don't have to explicitly import stuff that is in the same package.

Also, when specifying the names of java objects, in the Manifest, you can elide the name of the app package.  Thus, e.g., if your app package is foo.bar, and you have a class named foo.bar.baz.Zqx3, you need only enter ".baz.Zqx3" (actually, you can even leave off the initial '.').

It is convenient to put your java in the same package as your app but it is absolutely not necessary.